# FIR filter in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to design a `FIR` filter in matlab with a low order 
I have a sequence `x1` and I want to filter it

```
u=rand(1,10000);
u1=u-0.5;
mu=0;
b=1;
x1=mu-b*sign(u1).*log(1-(2*abs(u1)));
n=5;
h1=[ 1 0.8 0.3];
y=filter(n,h1,x1);
```

when I run the code I get a big matris `1*10000`

Am I doing right ?

what matris `1*10000` means ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `u=rand(1,10000);`, you define your input signal to have dimensions *1x10000*. Then, you apply some transformation to the amplitude to get the signal `x1`; but the dimensions are kept. So, the filtered signal `y` has dimensions *1x10000*.

The dimension *1x10000* means that you have a matrix with *1* row and *10000* columns, basically *10000* samples (points).

Comment: how to plot the output ?? Is there anything can be plotted?? thanks